# Naming {Binding} when you have more then 1 type on 1 window

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

If, on a WPF window, you have more than 1 {Binding}  for a parameter, is it possible to name them ?

For example for images i have (in the XAML part): `Visibility="{Binding}"` but also on some textboxes i want to make `IsEnabled="{Binding}"`
Is there some way to name them ? So that in the code in the backside (.cs side) it will pick the right one ?

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply have view model wrapping those properties into single object:

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool imagesVisibility;
    private bool isTextBoxEnabled;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public bool ImagesVisibility
    {
        get { return this.imagesVisibility; }
        set
        {
            this.imagesVisibility = value;
            this.PropertyChanged(this,
                new PropertyChangedEventArgs("ImagesVisibility"));
        }
    }

    public bool IsTextBoxEnabled
    {
        // ... similar as with ImagesVisibility property implementation
    }
}
```

*Note that you'll also need a boolean to visibility converter, which examples of you can find on StackOverflow ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7000819/binding-a-button-visibility-to-bool-value-in-viewmodel))... or [elsewhere](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.booleantovisibilityconverter.aspx).*

Then, you simply set instance of `ViewModel` to your form data context:

```
public MyForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = new ViewModel();
}
```

You can then do images binding like `Visibility="{Binding ImagesVisibility}"` and textbox `IsEnabled="{Binding IsTextBoxEnabled}"`.

Comment: it looks like this will work, will dive into this and let you know if i was able to get it to work :)

Comment: mmm ok, i think i have it all set up correct now, sho erm.. how do i call it in code now ? :P

Comment: Aah yes. sorry, im still in the first stages of learning c# and WPF hehe. It works indeed perfect. But what do i use if (for example) i now want to enable all the textboxes again. that i can do with 1 command now right ?

Comment: @Dante: yep, that can be done with 1 command. All this command would have to do it to change `ViewModel.IsTextBoxEnabled` property to `true`. Then, thanks to `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface changes will be propagated to all bound items (textboxes in this case) and update them accordingly.

Comment: thats what i thought too, but when i put in 'ViewModel.IsTextBoxEnabled = true' in a method, it returns in the errorbox: An object reference is required for the non-static field,method,or property 'WpfApplication1.ViewModel.IsTextBoxEnabled.get'

Comment: darn, now that thing throws me a nullreferenceExeption.. and the darn book that i bought learning c# doesnt really explain these wpf stuff hehe. i guess i have some name not matching correct.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6740/discussion-between-jimmy-keen-and-dante1986)

Comment: hehe switching true/false trough button works. only how i can have 1 already set to true on the start, keep trowing a NRE :/