# Hide/Show DataGrid based on Selected ListBoxItem in WPF

Tags: wpf, datagrid, listbox

I have a `ListBox`:

```
<ListBox Name="ListB" SelectedIndex="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Account}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <TextBlock FontSize="16" Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="3"> 
                    <TextBlock.Text>
                        <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} {1}" >
                            <Binding Path="AccountNumber" />
                            <Binding Path="Name" />
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </TextBlock.Text>
                </TextBlock>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Based on the `AccountNumber` I want to `Show/Hide` `DataGrid's` that are bound to the ListBoxItems:

```
<!--DataGrid 1-->       
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=ListB, Path=SelectedItem}">
..................
</DataGrid>

 <!--DataGrid 2-->      
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=ListB, Path=SelectedItem}">
..................
</DataGrid>
```

Is there any if/else in WPF? For example

```
if SelectedItem in ListBox has an AccountNumber 100 
      than show DataGrid 1 and hide DataGrid 2
else hide DataGrid 1 and show DataGrid 2.
```

Thank you in advance for the tips.

Comment: Can you just handle the SelectionChanged Event for your List, then perform your logic there?

Comment: Yes it worked using SelectionChanged Event in the code behind. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately WPF does not come with if/then/else structures. You have to build up a work-arround or use frameworks, which can solve your issue. One possible solution is to use blend sdk's interaction trigger framework:

```
xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity" 
xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions"
```

The behavior you mention would be implemented as following:

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
   <!-- One Trigger for equal 100 -->
   <ei:DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=SelectedItem.AccountNumber,
                                     ElementName=ListB}"
                   Value="100">
      <ei:ChangePropertyAction TargetName="DataGrid1" 
                               PropertyName="Visibility" 
                               Value="Collapsed" />
      <ei:ChangePropertyAction TargetName="DataGrid2" 
                               PropertyName="Visibility" 
                               Value="Visible" />

   </ei:DataTrigger> 

   <!-- One Trigger for not equal 100 -->
   <ei:DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=SelectedItem.AccountNumber,
                                     ElementName=ListB}"
                   Comparison="NotEqual"
                   Value="100">
      <ei:ChangePropertyAction TargetName="DataGrid1" 
                               PropertyName="Visibility" 
                               Value="Visible" />
      <ei:ChangePropertyAction TargetName="DataGrid2" 
                               PropertyName="Visibility" 
                               Value="Collapsed" />

   </ei:DataTrigger> 

</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

You will need to include **System.Windows.Interactivity.dll** into your project references.
Also required would be **Microsoft.Expression.Interactions.dll**

Another solution would be to bind the visibility of your DataGrids directly to SelectedItem.AccountNumber and attach and IValueConverter, which extracts the Visibility according to logic.

Using the SelectionChanged Event of the ListBox would also work, but becomes pretty much unreadable and may be redundant. If you follow the MVVM approach, your code behind should be almost empty.

Comment: Hi JanW. I included the System.Windows.Interactivity DLLs into my project but i get many errors: Property not found, Operand not found. With code behind worked as PGallagher suggested, but i would like to do it the right way with MVVM approach even though i am satisfied with the result.

Comment: Hey Georg, sorry I reproduced the solution from my mind. If you look up the classes on MSDN, you will see that I mistyped those: Property should be PropertyName and Operand should be Comparison. I correct these two in my answer. [DataTrigger on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.expression.interactivity.core.datatrigger.comparison%28v=expression.40%29.aspx) [ChangePropertyAction on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.expression.interactivity.core.changepropertyaction.propertyname%28v=expression.40%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

This would be straightforward if you were using a MVVM framework.

Add a BooleanToVisibility converter to your View as in [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7000819/binding-a-button-visibility-to-bool-value-in-viewmodel), with boolean properties to control the visibility of each grid in the ViewModel which are updated whenever the ListBox.SelectedItem is changed.