# How to set property of control from another class

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I have a progressBar control on page.
All data getting by 
this.DefaultViewModel["Items"] = feedAllCinemas.Cinemas;
where feeAllCinemas placed in another class.

I need to control visibility of progressBar in feedAllCinemas class.

Comment: What property of feedAllCinemas trigger the visibility change?  Use that property as the binding source of the ProgressBar's Visibility property, perhaps with a converter.

Comment: you should take a look at this [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7000922/1993545)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One (dirty yet simple) way to do this is to pass the progress bar instance to the feedAllCinemas class.

```
class feedAllCinemas
{
   ProgressBar m_ProgressBar;

   public feedAllCinemas(ProgressBar pbar)
   {
        m_ProgressBar = pbar;
   }

   void someMethod()
   {
         m_ProgressBar.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
   }
}
```