# Binding to a method with parameter in XAML using polymorphism in ViewModel

Tags: wpf, mvvm, binding

I have a TabControl with six tabs in my ResultView. The ViewModel that sits behind this View can be either a ResultTypeOneViewModel or ResultTypeTwoViewModel, each of which derives from ResultViewModel but you can interchangeably use the result viewer with either result type.

The difference is that in ResultTypeOneViewModel, tabs 1 & 3 need to be visible and the rest hidden.
In ResultTypeTwoViewModel, tabs 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 need to be visible and tab 1 hidden.

I wanted to do this via something like

```
<TabItem Name="1" Visibility={Binding IsTabVisible(0)}>
<TabItem Name="2" Visibility={Binding IsTabVisible(1)}>
<TabItem Name="3" Visibility={Binding IsTabVisible(2)}>
etc...
```

And have an abstract method declaration in ResultsViewModel such as

```
public abstract Visibility IsTabVisible(int index);
```

And in ResultsOneViewModel have

```
public override Visibility IsTabVisible(int index)
{
    if (index == 0 || index == 2) return Visibility.Visible;
    return Visibility.Hidden;
}
```

And in ResultsTwoViewModel have

```
public override Visibility IsTabVisible(int index)
{
    if (index == 0) return Visibility.Hidden;
    return Visibility.Visible;
}
```

But I cannot figure out how to call a method like this with a parameter through bindings iN WPF XAML.

Can anyone suggest how I can do this or if it's not possible via this method, another way I could solve this problem?

Comment: you're doing it all wrong. Create an `ObservableCollection<ViewModel>` and bind your `TabControl.ItemsSource` to that. then create a `bool IsVisible` value in the ViewModel and bind the `Visibility` of the Tab Items to that using a `BoolToVisibilityConverter`.

Comment: Visibility is purely UI (WPF), and has no mean for ViewModel. Change it for Boolean, and use BooleanToVisibilityConverter in binding.

Comment: HighCore, good idea to do it like that, Ive created a BaseResultViewModel class that I have an OBservableCollection of and binding that to the ItemsSource property of the TabControl. Problem is, the TabItem needs Header, HeaderStyle, Content properties etc. How do I get the ViewModel to provide all the dependency properties eg Header, Style, Content to the TabControl?

Comment: should `<TabItem Name="1" Visibility={Binding IsTabVisible[0]}>` work

Answer (score 12):

To answer your question directly, you can use the `ObjectDataProvider` to call a method for you so you can work with the results:

```
xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
xmlns:Windows="clr-namespace:System.Windows;assembly=PresentationCore"

...

<Window.Resources>
    <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="IsTab1VisibleMethod" 
        ObjectType="{x:Type Windows:Visibility}" IsAsynchronous="True" 
        MethodName="IsTabVisible">
        <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
            <System:Int32>0</System:Int32>
        </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
    </ObjectDataProvider>
</Window.Resources>
```

You should then be able to access the result like this (but you'd need one of these for each `TabItem`):

```
<TabItem Visibility="{Binding Source={StaticResource IsTab1VisibleMethod}}" />
```

However, it's generally not good practice to manipulate UI properties such as `Visibility` in code, so a better idea would be to use a `BooleanToVisibilityConverter` to `Bind` the `Visibility` properties to `bool` values as @Highcore suggested. You can see an example of this in the [Binding a Button Visibility to bool value in ViewModel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7000819/binding-a-button-visibility-to-bool-value-in-viewmodel) post here on StackOverflow.

In my opinion, an even better solution would be to simply provide one view for every view model.

Comment: Is there a way to do two way data binding with a parameter similar to this? This looks like it would only work for setting the value in the element from the method but I'd like two way binding. I wonder if I have a design problem since I'm in this situation...

Comment: Oh I guess the way to do it is with a converter that can convert back too. I think...

Comment: @Skychan, it depends what you mean by parameter. You could probably just wrap it in a property and simply data bind to it.

Comment: Thanks. Whatever it was I was trying to do that was similar to this, I got it to work. I think it ended up being a simple data bind to a property.

Answer (score 3):

A better suggestion to this question is to use style.DataTrigger in style of TabItem like this:

```
<TabItem>
    <TabItem.Style>
        <Style target="{x:Type TabItem}">
            <Style.DataTriggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsTabVisible}" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value = "Collapsed"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.DataTrigers>
        </Style>
    <TabItem.Style>
</TabItem>
```

Comment: Where do you pass the parameter to IsTabVisible() ?

Comment: It's a boolean property.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an indexer property to be able to pass a single parameter to a property. Although it's probably not very intuitive to return a boolean value from an indexer property it works fine for me. Also keep in mind the indexer property looses it's expected functionality.

```c
    class MyClass
    {
        public bool this[int tabNumber]
        {
            get
            {
                // Do logic to determine visibility here or in a separate method
                return IsTabVisible(tabNumber);
            }
        }

        bool IsTabVisible(int tabNumber)
        {
            bool result;

            // Method logic...

            return result;
        }
    }
```

So in XAML you can use the class name and provide a parameter between square brackets.

```
<TabItem Visibility="{Binding MyClass[0]}}"/>
```

If you need to raise a NotifyPropertyChanged for the indexer property use:

```c
    NotifyPropertyChanged("Item[]");
```

I don't know if this fits into the MVVM pattern but it could be useful for anyone who wants to bind to a method with a single parameter.

Comment: This is indeed a hack and WPF may complain "MyClass is not a collection", but I've found it useful. It should only be used in very isolated, specific use-cases, though.

Comment: There is one extra "}" in the code: `<TabItem Visibility="{Binding MyClass[0]}}"/>`