# windows phone Binding to two property

Tags: xaml, binding

I have a `Button`, and I want the button to be visible only when `Condition A == true` and `Condition B == true`.

Now， my `viewModel` already have two Property whose return type is  `boolean`.
So is it possible to achieve it with `XAML Binding`？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want your button to be visible depending on two properties then in this case it would be better you make a Visibility Property in your **Viewmodel** and bind that property to Button **Visibility Property in Xaml**.

For example :-

In Viewmodel create Visibility property -

```
    private Visibility _visBtn = Visibility.Collapsed;

    public Visibility VisBtn 
    {
        get { return _visBtn ; }
        set
        {
            _visBtn = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("VisBtn "); // INotifyPropertyChanged Implemented 
        }
    }
```

You have to just set this property according to your logic. like :-

```
If(Condition A == true && Condition B == true)
    VisBtn = Visibility.Visible;
```

Now Bind this property to Button In Xaml Like -

```
<Button Content="My Button" Visibility="{Binding VisBtn }" />
```

**Note** :- Make sure that you have implemented **INotifyPropertyChanged** In your Viewmodel and Your Xaml Page **DataContext** is set to corresponding **Viewmodel** properly.

**Second Case** :- 
If you want to set your button Visibility on basis of single bool property then you can implement **BooleanToVisibility** Converter this converter map Boolean property to Visibility type.

Then [**How to implement boolean to visibility Converter**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20295118/how-to-implement-a-booltovisibilityconverter) help you.