# Get Parent UI elements in User Control Window Phone 8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I am newbie to Window mobile 8 development . I have page with 5 user controls and in one of the user control i want to set text of textbox which is present in some other user control, how can i do this . Is there a way where i can get list of the ui elements visible to user ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using visualTreeHelper to get list of all the elements present on screen ,irrespective of which user control they are present in .

```
        Panel theParent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(this) as Panel;
        theParent.FindName("Name of the element")
```

Comment: May be add an explanation of "what you are doing" with your code?

Comment: This answer was exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Hope you are using [MVVM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg405484%28v=pandp.40%29.aspx) pattern .If yes , add a `view model` property for the text and bind this to the textbox .

Update this property whenever you want to change the value of the text box.

Use a [visibility converter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20344739/461561) if you want to change the visibility also.

Comment: Thank for reply .. i solved this problem using VisualTreeHelper