# How to diplay/call an UserControl from another UserControl at click both situated in one MainWindow (C#/Xaml)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls

I'm pretty stuck right now, i'm gonna explain my problem and what i want. 
In my **solution** i have a **mainWindow**, in that **MainWindow** i call the **first userControl** Who is situated in an **userControlLibrary**. I'ts a menu with button. I want when i click on the first button of the first userControl, i want put the **visibility** of the **second usercontrol** to **visible** (too situated in the **userControlLibrary**). But i try many things but no one works.

The first userControl is **UC_MenuSlider** and **UC_Start_Study** is the second who have to be visibile after click on the button on the first one. At launch **UC_Start_Study is hidden**.

This is a part of the code of my **Mainwindow**:

```
<Grid Name="MainGrid">

    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <UserControlLibrary:UC_StartStudy x:Name="UC_Start_Study"  Grid.Column="1" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" Margin="70 0 0 0" Visibility="Hidden"/>

   <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.1*" MaxWidth="240" MinWidth="240" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <UserControlLibrary:UC_MenuSlider x:Name="UC_MenuSlider"  Grid.Column="0"/>
   </Grid>

</Grid>
```

A part of the code of my first **UserControl (UC_MenuSlider)**:

```
<Grid Name="Grid_Menu" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
     <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>


    <Button x:Name="Start_Study"   Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"  Margin="0" Content="Start Study" FontSize="16" Click="Start_Study_Click">
    </Button>
</Grid>
```

At first a basic event,just an event click in my first userControl. with code behind like that:

```
public void Start_Study_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var startStudy = new UserControlLibrary.UC_StartStudy();
    startStudy.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
}
```

Don't works. Then i use 'RoutedEvent' But I don't really understand who it works.

I hope my question was enough clear, thanks in advance for your anwsers

Comment: Most reliable would be to use *binding*. Provide a dependency property in `UserControl1`, which value should control `UserControl2` visibility, bind `UserControl2` visibility to it (if you use `bool`, then you have to use converter, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7000819/1997232) question).

Comment: ok i'm going see this thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is because you are creating a new `UC_StartStrudy` and set its `Visibility` to `Visible`. What you really need is to set `Visibility` of the one in your `XAML`: `UC_Start_Study`

```
public void Start_Study_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   UC_Start_Study.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
}
```

And you could also use XAML databinding the `Visibility` property of your `UC_StartStrudy`, and set its value in your code:

XAML:

```
<Window.Resourses>
     <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooltoVisible" />
</Window.Resourse>

.....
<UserControlLibrary:UC_StartStudy x:Name="UC_Start_Study"  Grid.Column="1" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" Margin="70 0 0 0" Visibility="{Binding IsUCStartStudyVisible,  Converter={StaticResource BooltoVisible}}"/>
```

Code (remember to implement [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx) ):

```
//implement INotifyPropertyChanged
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;


private void RaisePropertyChange(String propertyName = "")
{
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
    {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}

//property for data binding
private bool _isucstartstudyvisible = false;
public bool IsUCStartStudyVisible
{
   get{return _isucstartstudyvisible;}
   set{_isucstartstudyvisible=value; RaisePropertyChange("IsUCStartStudyVisible");}
}

//your event to change the visibility
public void Start_Study_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   IsUCStartStudyVisible=true;
}
```

Comment: @Unkle-Wik, you need to implement [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx) see my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you are taking a new instance of UC_StartStudy() as you have already added this in your MainWindow.

Can't you simply turn the visibility of UC_Start_Study as visible within the code.

Let me show you how you can do this.
try

```
  public void Start_Study_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
              this.UC_Start_Study.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }
```