# UWP buttons inside Listview items

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, uwp, uwp-xaml

I'm working on my first UWP app and I want create a UI like this  [image]. For each list item (project) there'll be a set of buttons. For certain list items(projects) some of these buttons will be disabled some times. So I need to disable and change the image for such button in those list items(projects).

I tried to implement it using a list view like this. But I am not sure how I can enable/disable some of those buttons depending on the condition.

Tried adding a DataContextChanged event and trying to access the buttons there. But not sure how I can access those buttons.

Please let me know whether the following approach is correct or is there a better way to do what I am trying to achieve in the above image.

```
 <ListView x:Name="stepsListView" Margin="10,0,0,0" RequestedTheme="Dark" FontSize="24" Background="{StaticResource procedure_app_white}" Foreground="Black" BorderThickness="1.5" BorderBrush="Transparent" ItemsSource="{Binding projectList}"  HorizontalAlignment="Left">
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>

    <!-- Item -->
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border BorderThickness="0,0,0,1" BorderBrush="#c0c0c0">
                <Grid Width="auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" DataContextChanged="Grid_DataContextChanged" >
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="30" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="7" Text="{Binding projectName}" Foreground="{StaticResource procedure_app_orange_text }" />

                    <Button x:Name="warningButton" Width="40" Height="40" Grid.Column="1"  Grid.Row="1" Tag="{Binding projectId}" Click="warningButtonClick" Foreground="{StaticResource procedure_app_orange_text }">
                        <Button.Background>
                            <ImageBrush ImageSource="Asset/step_ncwr.png">
                            </ImageBrush>
                        </Button.Background>
                    </Button>
                    <Button x:Name="commentButton" Width="40" Height="40" Grid.Column="2"   Grid.Row="1"  Tag="{Binding projectId}" Click="CommentButtonClick" Foreground="{StaticResource procedure_app_orange_text }" IsTapEnabled="True">
                    <Button.Background>
                        <ImageBrush ImageSource="Asset/step_comment.png">
                        </ImageBrush>
                    </Button.Background>
                    </Button>
                    <Button x:Name="imageButton" Width="40" Height="40" Grid.Column="3"  Grid.Row="1"  Tag="{Binding projectId}" Click="ImageButtonClick" Foreground="{StaticResource procedure_app_orange_text }">
                        <Button.Background>
                            <ImageBrush ImageSource="Asset/step_image.png">
                            </ImageBrush>
                        </Button.Background>
                    </Button>
                </Grid>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is to variable dependent on what structure you've gone with so I am going to make some assumptions and roll with it.

First I am going to assume your `ViewModel` has an `ObservableCollection` called `ProjectList` and that this `ProjectList` is made up of `ProjectModel`'s

ProjectModel.cs

```
public class ProjectModel : INotifyPropertyChanged{
      private bool _isNcwrEnabled;
      public bool IsNcwrEnabled{
          get{ return _isNcwrEnabled; }
          set{ _isNcwrEnabled = value; OnPropertyChanged("IsNcwrEnabled"); }
      }
      private bool _isCommentEnabled;
      public bool IsCommentEnabled{
          get{ return _isCommentEnabled; }
          set{ _isCommentEnabled= value; OnPropertyChanged("IsCommentEnabled"); }
      }
      private bool _isImageEnabled;
      public bool IsImageEnabled{
          get{ return _isImageEnabled; }
          set{ _isImageEnabled= value; OnPropertyChanged("IsImageEnabled"); }
      }

    public void OnPropertyChanged(String prop)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;

        if (handler != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

In your `ViewModel` you should have

```
ObservableCollection<ProjectModel> ProjectList {get; private set; }
```

Finally in your `View`

```
    <Button IsEnabled="{Binding IsNcwrEnabled}" x:Name="warningButton" Width="40" Height="40" Grid.Column="1"
            Grid.Row="1" Tag="{Binding projectId}" Click="warningButtonClick" 
            Foreground="{StaticResource procedure_app_orange_text }">
         <Button.Background>
             <ImageBrush ImageSource="Asset/step_ncwr.png"/>
         </Button.Background>
    </Button>
    <Button IsEnabled="{Binding IsCommentEnabled}" x:Name="commentButton" Width="40" Height="40" Grid.Column="2"
            Grid.Row="1"  Tag="{Binding projectId}" Click="CommentButtonClick" 
            Foreground="{StaticResource procedure_app_orange_text }" IsTapEnabled="True">
         <Button.Background>
             <ImageBrush ImageSource="Asset/step_comment.png"/>
         </Button.Background>
     </Button>
     <Button IsEnabled="{Binding IsImageEnabled}" x:Name="imageButton" Width="40" Height="40" Grid.Column="3"
             Grid.Row="1"  Tag="{Binding projectId}" Click="ImageButtonClick" 
             Foreground="{StaticResource procedure_app_orange_text }">
         <Button.Background>
             <ImageBrush ImageSource="Asset/step_image.png"/>
         </Button.Background>
     </Button>
```

**Summary of Changes**

1. The models in the collection that your `ListView` is bound to needs to contain enabled properties for your `Buttons` to bind to
2. In your `View`, bind your `Buttons` to your new properties

Comment: Thank you very much Anthony for the detailed answer. So if I want to change the image when disabled. I need to define another property in the ProjectModel like ncwrImage and set the image depending on the condition and set like ImageSource="{Binding ncwrImage }" in the ImageBrush . Is that correct?

Comment: If you wanted to change the images I would create a Data trigger that switched the image source based on the model's enabled property

Comment: @Madhu if this answer works for you please don't forget to check mark and upvote so others can use it

Comment: Thanks Anthony, I'll mark this as the answer. But still I couldn't find a way to do these two things. <br>1. how to hide some buttons using binding. Looks like I need to set Visibility=collapse. But not sure how to do it using the bool I have. I tried this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7000819/binding-a-button-visibility-to-bool-value-in-viewmodel but it doesn't seem to work on uwp. <br>2. How to change the ImageBrush  ImageSource in the above code, using that bool. I looked at the link you have provided, but those style triggers are not supported in uwp. :-(

Comment: @Madhu if you have more questions then just post them in new Stack Overflow questions :-)

Comment: I added a new question as you suggested http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38374143/uwp-app-show-hide-button-using-binding