# Enable/disable ui element usercontrol in wpf c# code behind

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls, code-behind

For a project, I create a Numpad and a keyboard.
Both are user controls and they are shown in a Window.

I want to use a button/toggle in xaml to enable the one or the other.
What is the best way to approach this in code- behind C#?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Don't use code-behind for that. Use a ViewModel Property and bind visibility to it.

Comment: Here is an example for a button: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7000819/binding-a-buttons-visibility-to-a-bool-value-in-viewmodel#7000922 . You should be able to replace the button with your controls.

Comment: Do you want to hide/ show your buttons or just enable disable them?

Comment: @MindSwipe As I read it, OP does not want to toggle the _buttons'_ visibility but the use the button to toggle visibility of another control.

Comment: @Fildor I understand that, but OPs wording is kinda confusing, he's saying he wants to "enable the one or the other" does he mean show/ hide the buttons or enabling/ disabling them?

Comment: _"... a Numpad and a keyboard. Both are user controls and they are shown in a Window."_ - I guess he's referring to those. @MindSwipe

Comment: @Fildor I know which controls hes referring to, but is he referring to the `Visibility` Property or the `IsEnabled` Property? Is he trying to make those controls disappear or simply make them so the User can't click on them?

Comment: @MindSwipe Ahhh, sorry! Now I got it. Yes, you are correct. Could be any of the two. L Hu: please clearify.

Answer (score 0):

Make a Button on the GUI and bind the Click event to a EventHandler in the Code Behind. This EventHandler basically just flip-flops the `IsEnabled` Property of the control Elements. Here is how something like this could look

```
private void BtnToggle_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //Do this with every button
    BtnToFlip.IsEnabled = !Btn.ToFlip.IsEnabled
}
```

This flip-flops between `IsEnabled` from `true` to `false`

**Note:** This is in no way shape or form the best way to do this, and I am aware this is not even remotely MVVM. This is just a simple answer to OP's question as he seems to be very new.

Comment: Exactly because OP is new to WPF I find it important to show the "correct way" to do it: Commands, ViewModel, Bindings.