# Can i write this code shorter? with loop or something

Tags: c#, wpf

Can i write this code shorter? with loop or something

```
        R1.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        R2.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        R3.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        R4.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        R5.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        R6.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        R7.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        R8.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        R9.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        R10.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
```

I dont want to do it in array because

its not efficiency

i tought about something like this

```
 for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++)
 {
   R+i.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
 }
```

is it possible?

thanks for the help :)

Comment: What are `Rx`? You could [enumerate children](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10279092/1997232) of certain container to access them in the loop. A better approach would be to separate view and model and have observable collection of `bool` to change controls visibility [using bindings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7000922/1997232).

Comment: Something like `foreach (var rect in canvas.Children.OfType<Rectangle>()) { rect.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a method that takes them as params and applies them via a loop

```
public void SetHidden(params R[] items)
{
    foreach(var r in items)
    {
        r.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
    }
}
```

and call it like

```
SetHidden(R1,R2,R3,R4,R5,R6,R7,R8,R9,R10);
```